# The Primitive and Basic Numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes, base-conversion

Your task is to generate the "Primitive and Basic" numbers, which are made like so:

Start with **1<sub>10</sub>**. Take the digits of its base-1 representation (**1<sub>10</sub> = 1<sub>1</sub>**) and interpret them as base-2 digits. This gives **1<sub>2</sub> = 1<sub>10</sub>**. Now, add the second prime number – **3<sub>10</sub>** – to the result. This will give you **4<sub>10</sub>**, which is our first "Primitive and Basic" (**PB**) number, or **PB(1)** (you can now see where I got the name from).

Next, take **4<sub>10</sub> = 100<sub>2</sub>** and interpret the digits of its base-2 representation as base-3 digits. This gives **100<sub>3</sub> = 9<sub>10</sub>**. Add the third prime number – **5<sub>10</sub>** – to the result, which gives **14<sub>10</sub>**. That's the second **PB** number, or **PB(2)**.

You can see where this is going: take **14<sub>10</sub> = 112<sub>3</sub>** and interpret the digits of its base-3 representation as base-4 digits. This gives **112<sub>4</sub> = 22<sub>10</sub>**. Add the fourth prime number – **7<sub>10</sub>** – to the result, which gives **29<sub>10</sub>**.

This continues on and on forever.

In general, **PB(n)** is equal to **PB(n-1)**, converted to base **n** and from base **n+1** to integer, plus the **(n+1)**<sup>th</sup> prime.

The first few terms of this sequence are:

```
4, 14, 29, 52, 87, 132, 185...
```

You must write a function or program that creates these numbers. It must take a positive integer **n** as input, and return **PB(n)**.

### I/O:

```
1 -> 4
5 -> 87
```

### Rules and specs:

- Your program must be able to handle all **PB** numbers below **2<sup>31</sup>-1**.
- Standard loopholes apply.
- The input may be 0-indexed or 1-indexed, whichever you prefer.
- The input is guaranteed to be a valid index.
- The output must be in base 10.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

*Unfortunately, there isn't an OEIS sequence for this. You can propose to OEIS to add this sequence in if you want.*

Comment: I find "turn it into base 3" misleading. That sounds like I should convert either 4 or 100 to base 3 which is either 11 or 10201. What you seem to intend is that the representation from the previous base should now be *treated as* digits in the next base.

Comment: What are we supposed to do? Create a program/function takes takes input and gives the nth PB term? Or are we supposed to generate all terms below 2^31-1?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading thing: your program must be able to handle terms that are up to `2^31-1`. It's meant to take an input `n` and return the output `PB(n)`.

Comment: I just hope all these comments get me the "Blue in the Face" hat

Comment: @MartinEnder I believe the base thing is kinda fixed. If it should be improved further, can you edit the post?

Comment: I think "*add the base-2 equivalent of the second prime*" would be more accurate and less confusing, as just "*add the second prime*". Same in the next two paragraphs.

Comment: @smls Wait, what? So you're saying I should just do "add the second prime" instead, right?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp: Yeah. I suggested an edit now.

Comment: @smls I looked at the revised edit, and I didn't really think that condensing it down would help with clarity - for me, at least, it made it more confusing, so I changed it to something like "the second prime in base-2", just to clarify the "process" of the sequence.

Comment: I didn't understand the task the first time I read it, so I rephrased it in an attempt to make it clearer. Please feel free to roll back any changes you disagree with.

Comment: @Dennis Wow, it looks much cleaner and clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 126 bytes

```
require("prime")
->n{o=4
(2..n).map{|i|j=i+1
r=[]
(r.unshift o%i;o/=i)while o>0
o=r.inject{|s,k|s*j+k}+Prime.first(j)[-1]}
o}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
’ß1¹?bḅ‘+‘ÆN$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYebh@YaHdtonPdzR@qhhhjYQH27zU/n//78pAA)

#### How it works

```
’ß1¹?bḅ‘+‘ÆN$  Main link. Argument: n

’              Decrement; yield n-1.
   ¹?          If n-1 is non-zero:
 ß               Recursively call the main link with argument n-1.
               Else:
  1              Yield 1.
     b         Convert the result to base n.
      ḅ‘       Convert from base n+1 to integer.
         ‘ÆN$  Increment n and yield the (n+1)-th prime.
        +      Add the results to both sides.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 66 bytes

```
Fold[IntegerDigits[#,#2-1]~FromDigits~#2+Prime@#2&,4,2~Range~#+1]&
```

Unnamed function taking a single (1-indexed) integer argument and returning an integer.

`Fold[...,4,2~Range~#+1]` iterates a function of two arguments, with the first argument beginning at `4` and thereafter set to the output of the previous iteration, while the second argument iterates over the set {3,4,...,`#`+1} (where `#` is the original integer argument).

The function in question is `IntegerDigits[#,#2-1]~FromDigits~#2+Prime@#2`. First, `IntegerDigits[#,#2-1]` converts the first argument into a list of its digits when written in the previous base; then, `...~FromDigits~#2` converts that list of digits back into an integer, assuming the digits are now in the current base. Finally, the `#2`th prime is added to the result.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 95 bytes

```
{my $b=1;(4,{grep(*.is-prime,2..*)[++$b]+.polymod($b xx*).&{sum $_ Z*($b+1 X**0..*)}}...*)[$_]}
```

Zero-based indexed.

#### Explanation:

Since the language's built-in `.base` and `.parse-base` methods are string-based, they only work up to base 36. So in order to fulfill the task requirement that large inputs must be supported, the base conversion is done as follows:

- `.polymod($b xx *)`: Convert the current number to a list representing its digits in base `$b`.
- `sum $_ Z* ($b+1 X** 0..*)`: Interpret the resulting digits as a number in base `$b+1`.